# How to use the scrollView correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to know how to correctly use a scrollview in a ViewController, I want it to scroll up and down normally
On iPhone 5s simulator is doesn't scroll right it leaves the textView at the bottom and the label2 and textview2 doesn't not show at all. So when scrolling down it just gives a blue color then at the bottom is the label1 and textview. 
Can you help me with my code?
Thank You in advance

```
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let sview = UIScrollView()
    sview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sview.backgroundColor = .cyan
    sview.contentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 940)

    return v
  }()
     self.view.addSubview(scrollView)


    scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
    scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true


    view.addSubview(label1)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([label1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
                                 label1.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 10),
                                 label1.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -10),
                                 label1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)])


    scrollView.addSubview(textView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label1.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
                                 textView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 10),
                                 textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -10),
                                 textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 550)
        ])
    scrollView.addSubview(label2)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([label2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
                                 label2.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 10),
                                 label2.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -10),
                                 label2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)])

    scrollView.addSubview(textView2)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([textView2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label2.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
                                 textView2.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 10),
                                 textView2.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -10),
                                 textView2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450)
        ])
     scrollView.addSubview(button)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20),
                                 button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -20),
                                 button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)])
}
```

Comment: Why `sview.contentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 940)`? Don't set the content size. You've set the scrollview's constraints to its superview. If you want it only to scroll vertically, then set its width constraint to its super view's width. Then try again, and see if it is renders any better. Also, should `label1` be a subview of the scrollview or a sibling view?

Comment: @ArRizzo so you mean take away the contentSize. and can you explain me your second question?

Comment: When I take it out, now it doesn't scroll at all, Why is it?

Comment: set the scrollView ContenSize height equals to view.frame.height +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set the `.contentSize` of the scroll view... use proper constraints and let auto-layout handle that for you.

To get that to work, your scroll view subviews (the *content*) need to define top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints, ***plus*** width and height - that determines the "scrollable area" (the `.contentSize`) without the need to hard-code the values.

Here is your code, slightly modified:

```
class JoseViewController: UIViewController {

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let sview = UIScrollView()
        sview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sview.backgroundColor = .cyan
        return sview
    }()

    let label1: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.text = "Label 1"
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.backgroundColor = .purple
        return v
    }()

    let label2: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.text = "Label 2"
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        return v
    }()

    let textView: UITextView = {
        let v = UITextView()
        v.text = "Text View 1"
        v.backgroundColor = .orange
        return v
    }()

    let textView2: UITextView = {
        let v = UITextView()
        v.text = "Text View 2"
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        return v
    }()

    let button: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.setTitle("The Button", for: .normal)
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        [scrollView, label1, textView, label2, textView2, button].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

        scrollView.addSubview(label1)
        scrollView.addSubview(textView)
        scrollView.addSubview(label2)
        scrollView.addSubview(textView2)
        scrollView.addSubview(button)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain scrollView to view, 8-pts padding on each side
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            // constrain label1 20-pts to top of scrollView, leading and trailing 10-pts to scrollView
            label1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            label1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            label1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            label1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),

            // constrain textView top to label1.bottom + 10-pts, leading and trailing 10-pts to scrollView
            textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label1.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 550),

            // constrain label2 top to textView.bottom + 10-pts, leading and trailing 10-pts to scrollView
            label2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            label2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            label2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            label2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),

            // constrain textView2 top to label2.bottom + 10-pts, leading and trailing 10-pts to scrollView
            textView2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label2.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            textView2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            textView2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            textView2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450),

            // constrain button at top-right of scrollView?
            button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 20),
            button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),

            // need at least one element to define the width of the "scrollable area"
            // so constrain label1 width to width of scrollView -20 pts (10-pts on each side)
            label1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, constant: -20),

            // need a bottom constraint to define the height of the "scrollable area"
            // so constrain bottom of textView2 to bottom of scrollView with 20-pts padding
            textView2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),

            ])

    }

}
```

Couple notes:

- Use `leading` and `trailing` anchors instead of `left` and `right`.
- group your constraints in a logical manner, including comments so you know what you're expecting
- during development, give elements background colors to make it easy to see the frame layouts

Results of the above code, on iPhone 7:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: it goes the oppsoite way the first label and textview are the only showing up and the label2 nor textView 2 and label1 and textview are always at the bottom

Comment: @JoseGarcia - I added screen-caps of the results of the ***exact*** code that I posted.